# How to set color on row using hashMap?

Tags: java, swing

I wanted to color the 7 rows in my case with all different colors but its not coloring entire row but only first column...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class UsingHashTable extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Object rowData[][] = { 
            { "Row1", "Row1", "Row1" },
            { "Row2", "Row2", "Row2" },
            { "Row3", "Row3", "Row3" },
            { "Row4", "Row4", "Row4" },
            { "Row5", "Row5", "Row5" },
            { "Row6", "Row6", "Row6" },
            { "Row7", "Row7", "Row7" }
        };
        Object columnNames[] = { "Column One", "Column Two", "Column Three" };
        JTable table = new JTable(rowData, columnNames);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Renderit());
        frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(300, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here I am using render class to do the job and initialize the Map 
then I am using the key to check for the row but its not helping ...

```
class Renderit extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    Map<Integer, Color> map = new HashMap<>();

    public  renderit() {
        map.put(0, Color.blue);
        map.put(1, Color.yellow);
        map.put(2, Color.red);
        map.put(3, Color.green);
        map.put(4, Color.pink);
        map.put(5, Color.orange);
        map.put(6, Color.magenta);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
            JTable table, Object value, 
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
            table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column
        );

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, Color> enp : map.entrySet()) {
            int key = enp.getKey();

            if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            } else if(key==row) {
                table.setBackground(enp.getValue());
            }
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

I don't know where am I making mistake please help.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but why do you have a chain of 7 `if-else`s if they all have the same condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the `getTableCellRendererComponent` method of your `Renderit` class.

1. As @ElanHamburger already mentioned,
   you have 7 if/else-branches all doing the same thing.
   Just one if-branch would have the same effect.
2. You set the background of the whole `table`.
   Instead you should set the background of only the cellRendererComponent `comp`.

All in all, your corrected method can look like this:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Color> enp : map.entrySet()) {
        int key = enp.getKey();

        if (key == row) {
            comp.setBackground(enp.getValue());
        }

    }

    return comp;
}
```

While the above code certainly works correctly,
it is still more complicated than needed.
You don't need to do iterate through your `HashMap` with a hand-written `for` loop.
Instead you can simply use the `HashMap`'s `get` method,
to find for a given `row` the according `Color`:

```
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value,
            isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    Color color = map.get(row);
    if (color != null) {
        comp.setBackground(color);
    }

    return comp;
}
```

Comment: But can you please tell why have you not used table.paint(); and when to use it....?

Comment: @anrdggle The TableCellRenderer (more precisely: the one which you got by
`super.getTableCellRendererComponent`) does the painting for you.
In Swing you never call `paint` by yourself. Instead you rely on Swing calling `paint` at appropriate times.
But that's a different (and very big) story.
Just google for ["swing paint"](https://www.google.de/search?q=swing+paint), and you'll find lots of excellent articles.